# Are these adb commands safe?

Tags: adb, locked-out

my phone gone locked after hard factory reset, waited for 3 days but still can't login. I've found a solution on internet that works, i need to use adb and use following commands on my phone:

> adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/secure --bind
>   name:s:user_setup_complete --bind value:s:1
>
> adb shell am start -n com.google.android.gsf.login/
>
> adb shell am start -n com.google.android.gsf.login.LoginActivity

what are these commands doing(especially first one)? Safe to use or makes a backdoor on my phone?

Comment: The first one just tells the device that the setup wizard was completed I believe, so it will skip the initial configuration wizard... Seems to me this was a potential bypass of FRP on Lollipop on older HTC devices, it is relatively safe and doesn't open a "backdoor". The other two are just starting normal services. Not sure how the last 2 would help at all, but it shouldn't hurt anything to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, It is safe. the first one code is about to validation on user: name as 'true', the others starts Login and jump it..

about the codes its ok. but if you use another one soft, it might be not safe.